# Unable to connect to tableau-it.homedepot.com:443 via Python code

Tags: python, openssl, ssl-certificate, tableau-api

I've downloaded successfully a certificate using a pyhton code, then I ran the following:

```
sudo cp tableau-it.homedepot.com_0.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/tableau.crt

ls /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Then, I have this code

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import certifi
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import csv
import json
import pathlib
#
carFilePath = "/etc/ssl/certs/tableau.pem"
crtCAFilePath = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
server = TSC.Server(SOURCE_SERVER_NAME, use_server_version=True)
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(token_name=tableauAccessToken, personal_access_token=tableauAccessTokenValue, site_id=SOURCE_SITE_NAME)
server.add_http_options({'verify': True, 'cert': carFilePath})
server.use_server_version()
print(server.version)

print('Checking connection to Tableau server...')
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    print('Logged in to source server successfully')
```

and when running the code above I've received the following:

```
request method get, url: https://tableau-it.homedepot.com//api/2.4/serverInfo
[18:27:57] Begin blocking request to https://tableau-it.homedepot.com//api/2.4/serverInfo
Error making request to server: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
[18:27:57] Request complete
[18:27:58] Async request returned: received HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
Response status: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
Could not get version info from server: <class 'OSError'>Response is not a http response?
versions: None, 2.4
request method get, url: https://tableau-it.homedepot.com//api/2.4/serverInfo
[18:27:58] Begin blocking request to https://tableau-it.homedepot.com//api/2.4/serverInfo
Error making request to server: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3845)')))
[18:27:58] Request complete
[18:27:59] Async request returned: received HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3845)')))
Response status: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3845)')))
Could not get version info from server: <class 'OSError'>Response is not a http response?
versions: None, 2.4
2.4
Checking connection to Tableau server...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 722, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 404, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1058, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 429, in connect
    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 418, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3845)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 800, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/auth/signin (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3845)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkConnTableau.py", line 41, in <module>
    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/endpoint.py", line 292, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/auth_endpoint.py", line 32, in sign_in
    url, data=signin_req, **self.parent_srv.http_options, allow_redirects=False
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/virtual_environments/tableauServerClient/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau-it.homedepot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/auth/signin (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3845)')))
```

I tried also pointing to the pem file, put in the code and created when the certificate is installed, without success.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks